# How to resize a parbox depending on the actual text width?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, parbox

**Context**

I'm working on a pseudocode package to write algorithms with multiline support. Then, long lines can be broken and the proper identation is handled accordingly. I do the job with `parbox`es.

The text looks better if it is left aligned, so `\RaggedRight` (from `ragged2e`) is used, as hyphenation also helps.

**The problem**

Each line of the code can have a comment, which is placed in the right margin. The text part is resized to make place for the comment.

Long comments also can span to multiple lines. When this happens, they have to be limited to a maximum witdh.

Unfortunately, when a comment has more than a single line, it doesn't touch the right margin, because the comment is left aligned inside the `parbox` and the size of the `parbox` is set to a fixed maximum width (see MWE).

**My question**

Is it possible to make the `parbox` (re)sized to the actual width of the text it will hold, so the **text** (and not the `parbox`) touchs the right margin, while keeping it left aligned?

**MWE**

The macro `\algparbox` is my implementation to handle the text and the comment. I've rewritten a cleaner version of it for this MWE, hiding details from the algorithmic stuff (like nesting control, for example).

Comments wider than `\largestcommentwidth` are broken in lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

%% uncomment to make parboxes visible
%\let\pb\parbox
%\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
%\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.01pt}
%\renewcommand{\parbox}[3][]{\fbox{\pb[#1]{#2}{#3}}} 

\def\commentleftsymbol{$\triangleright$}

\newlength{\commentwidth}
\newlength{\largestcommentwidth}
\setlength{\largestcommentwidth}{3.5cm}
\newlength{\commentsep}
\newlength{\commentsymbollength}


\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\algparbox}[3]{%
    % #1: comment
    % #2: text
    % #3: hangindent
    \def\comment{#1}
    \ifx\comment\empty%
        \setlength{\commentsep}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\commentwidth}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\commentsymbollength}{0pt}%
    \else%
        \setlength{\commentsep}{0.25cm}%
        \settowidth{\commentwidth}{\slshape\comment}%
        \settowidth{\commentsymbollength}%
            {\hspace{\commentsep}\commentleftsymbol\hspace{\commentsep}}%
    \fi%
    %
    % HERE: how to adjust \commentwidth to actual text width?
    %
    \ifdim\commentwidth>\largestcommentwidth\relax%
        \setlength{\commentwidth}{\largestcommentwidth}%
    \fi%
    %
    \noindent%
    \parbox[t]%
        {\dimexpr \linewidth - \commentwidth - \commentsymbollength \relax}%
        {\setlength{\hangindent}{#3}\RaggedRight#2\strut}%
    \ifx\comment\empty\else%
        \hspace{\commentsep}\commentleftsymbol\hspace{\commentsep}%
        \parbox[t]{\commentwidth}{\slshape\RaggedRight\comment\strut}%
    \fi%
    \par
}

% short excerpt from kantlipsum text
\newcommand{\kant}{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only beused as a canon for our understanding. The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give riseto the architectonic of practical reason.}

\begin{document}
\algparbox{}{Short text without comment}{1cm}
\algparbox{short comment}{Short text with short comment}{1cm}
\algparbox{this is a longer comment}{Short text with long comment}{1cm}\marginpar{$\longleftarrow$~How to avoid this and make the text touch the right margin?}
\algparbox{}{Long text without comment. \kant}{1cm}
\algparbox{short comment}{Long text with short comment. \kant}{1cm}
\algparbox{some little longer comment}{Long text with long comment. \kant}{1cm}\marginpar{$\longleftarrow$~And this?}
\algparbox{longer comment. \kant}{Long text. \kant\ \kant\ \kant}{1cm}\marginpar{Hyphenation helps here, but it's not a solution}
\end{document}
```

My package is `algxpar` and is in [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/algxpar), but this is irrelevant for the question. :-)

Comment: The varwidth environment uses the smallest width within a given limit.  However, you still have to calculate how much space is left if you don't start on the left side.  You could use \tikzmark and tikspagenodes.

Comment: don't use `\RaggedRight` for comments: `{\slshape\RaggedRight\comment\strut}`

Comment: @touhami Justified text in comments looks even worse, specially with longer words.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I didn't know about `varwidth`. This answers my question!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was answered in the comments.

Comment: I agree the question was answerd, as `varwidth` works. But why 'off-topic'? Just to understand...

Comment: Rather strange to close a question because it has an answer :)